# Attachments are included only on manual resend, but not on initial form submission

Tags: 7, webforms, mimemail

Using Webform and [Mimemail](https://www.drupal.org/project/mimemail) to send HTML emails and uploaded files attached to emails.

When submitting the form, the file is not attached to the email. The box is ticked.

[image]

If you edit the submitted submission and click 'resend email', it attaches the PDF file to the email.

[image]

There are no errors on dblog.

How do I attach the files to the emails when the user submits the form with uploaded files?

Comment: Some permission maybe?

Comment: Also, it may be worth checking if the email is being generated and sent before the drupal file system has actually finished saving the file. You may be able to use rules to delay/trigger the email notification.

Comment: So I checked the permissions, there was Mimemail permission called `Send arbitrary files`, but it still didn't do nothing. I ended up googling to this https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_scheduled_export/issues/2940537#comment-12457163 and it gave me a hint to set webform files directory from private to public. That seemed to have fixed it. How do I mark this as answered?